# C++ 64bit timestamp to 32bit time_t

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I want to convert a 64bit timestamp (in us) to a date string in order to set system date via system command "date". I found/implemented this solution:

```
char loc_ach_buf[25];
uint64_t loc_ui64_TimeStamp_us;
time_t loc_t_TimeStamp_s;
...         
loc_t_TimeStamp_s = loc_ui64_TimeStamp_us / 1000000;
strftime(loc_ach_buf, sizeof(loc_ach_buf), "date %Y%m%d%H%M.%S", gmtime(&loc_t_TimeStamp_s));
system(loc_ach_buf);
```

This works fine, but my problem is, that time_t is a 32bit value on my system and so there will be problems [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). Any ideas how to solve this? Or are there alternatives to strftime.

Comment: Remember Year 2000? Do not solve 2038 problem now. Wait till 2037 - then they will pay much more than now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why use the system command 'date'? Use the [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call.

Comment: I don't think it'll be around in 2038, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which toolset you're working with but the Microsoft compiler supports a function [_localtime64_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which will convert a 64-bit time value to the tm structure that you can then use with [strftime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If your CRT doesn't support 64-bit time functions have a look at this: [A version of gmtime() that works around the 2038 bug](http://2038bug.com/index.php/articles/43-code/62-a-version-of-gmtime-that-works-around-the-2038-bug)